# Indefinite integral $\int t \cdot \cos^3(t^2)dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am having trouble integrating
$$\int t \cdot \cos^3(t^2)dt$$

#### Progress

I have made $u=t^2$ which makes the problem $1/2 \int \cos^3(u) du$.

After writing that out I subsituted $v=\sin(u)$ and got $1/2 \int  (1-v^2)dv $  ... then I integrated and got $\frac12[v-v^3/3]$, after that I plugged in $v$ which would make it $\frac12  [\sin(u)-\sin^3(u)/3]$.

Is this correct so far, and what else should be done?

Comment: Hint: there is quite an obvious substitution which might help

Comment: I have made u=t^2 which makes the problem 1/2 integral cos^3(u) du

Comment: Well if you've done that, explain it in the question, because it always helps us to know what progress you've made.

Comment: Next write $\cos^{3}u=\cos^{2}u\cos u=(1-\sin^{2}u)\cos u$ and substitute again.

Comment: Sorry its my first time on here , ok after writing that out I subsituted v=sin(u) and got 1/2 integral (1-v^2)dv ....then I integrated and got 1/2[v-v^3/3] , after that I plugged in v which would make it 1/2[sin(u)-sin^3(u)/3]

Comment: You just integrated, so you're done. Just substitute $u$ back in and don't forget your constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int t\cos^3(t^2)\,dt=
\frac{1}{2}\int\cos^3(u)\,du=
\frac{1}{2}\int\cos^2(u)\,d\big(\sin(u)\big)=
\frac{1}{2}\int\big(1-\sin^2(u)\big)\,d\big(\sin(u)\big)=
\frac{1}{2}\Big(\int\,d\big(\sin(u)\big)-\int\sin^2(u)\,d\big(\sin(u)\big)\Big)=
\frac{1}{2}\Big(\sin(u)-\frac{1}{3}\sin^3(u)\Big)+c$$

subsitute $u=t^2$ to get 
$$\frac{1}{2}\Big(\sin(t^2)-\frac{1}{3}\sin^3(t^2)\Big)+c$$